# Proving convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to prove that the following sequence is convergent:

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4(1-a_n)}$$

And $a_0=0$. I should show that the sequence is increasing and bounded. I could not find a way to go about it. A good hint would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is $a_0$ ?

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot to write that. $a_0=0$

Comment: Try Banach fixed-point theorem.

Comment: @REr we have not had that yet

Comment: We can prove by induction that $a_n\lt 1/2$. Also, by induction, increasingness, if $a_{n}\gt a_{n-1}$ then $a_{n+1}\gt a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Suppose it converge and let denote $\ell$ the limit. Then,$$\ell=\frac{1}{4(\ell-1)}\implies \ell=...$$

Now prove by induction (very easy) that $a_n\leq \ell$ for all $n$ and that $(a_n)$ is increasing.

You will have your result.

Actually, you can prove by induction that $a_n\leq 1$ for all $n$ and that $(a_n)$ is increasing... you will also get the result. The reason that we solve $\ell=\frac{1}{4(\ell-1)}$ is to have at least one upper-bound (and in fact the smallest one, but it's the easiest to find when you don't have more information).

Comment: But did you assume first that the sequence is convergent? Then it would follow that the sequence is increasing. Can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: I indeed supposed it converge to know what would be the limit. Then if it's increasing, the limit would be the supremum. Therefore, to show that it converge, you show that it's upper bounded by $\ell$ and that it's increasing.

Comment: I can show that it is bounded by induction. But it is still not clear to me how to show increasingness? Also, solving the equation gives a quadratic function, I still do not understand it